# Not able to get the output when trying to connect to a mysql db using python

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote this code mentioned below to get a basic select statement output from mysql database using python.

The code is :

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", message='the sets module is deprecated')

import MySQLdb

import sys


try:
    db =MySQLdb.connect(host='********',user='Admin',passwd='******',db='data')

except Exception as e:

    sys.exit('Not working')

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('select * from user')

results = cursor.fetchall()

print results
```

But the output that is get is :

((1L,), (2L,))

Please assist
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it means you have those entry in db. Try running same query directly on the database and share output

Comment: its just a select query which gives me the correct output when i do it from mysql command line. @optimus

Comment: Can you paste actual content of table. that is output of the command line sql query?